# The HTTP verb POST used to access path .... is not allowed

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webforms, webmethod

I have a aspx file and I would like to request to WebMethod in same page with Ajax. However I get some error(you can see below) Actually this code worked before change my server.

Server config

- IIS 7.5
- .Net Framwork 4
- Windows Server 2008 R2

This is my Webmethod code in "Page.aspx"

```
[WebMethod]
public static string deleteOpenedSegment(decimal segmentID)
{
    bool success = Helper.DeleteSegment(segmentID);
    if (success)
    {
        return "true";
    }
    else
    {
        return "false";
    }
}
```

And this is my Javascript method in Page.aspx

```
jQuery.ajax({
       url: 'Page.aspx/deleteOpenedSegment',
       type: "POST",
       data: "{'segmentID':" + getSelectedSegment().attr('id') + "}",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (data) {
                  alert("okey");
                }
       });
```

And also this is capture about request from Google Chrome Web Developer Tool
[image]

Error Log

> The HTTP verb POST used to access path
>   '/............/Page.aspx/deleteOpenedSegment' is not allowed.
>   
>   System.Web.HttpException The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/......./Page.aspx/deleteOpenedSegment' is not allowed.
>   
>   System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/......./Page.aspx/getSegmentHistory' is not allowed.   
>        at System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
>        at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>        at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,Boolean&  completedSynchronously)

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

Comment: What are you trying to delete, is it any file you want to delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem. Actually I did not consciously but probleb was fixed. I did Windows Updates after problem solved :)
Updates shown below might be help another programmers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have also use this type of code and I am able to delete my item without any problem, see my code

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
        public static string DeleteCartItem(string catId)
        {
            Customer thisCustomer = Customer.Current;
            var cart = new ShoppingCart(thisCustomer.SkinID, thisCustomer, CartTypeEnum.ShoppingCart, 0, false);
            cart.RemoveItem(Convert.ToInt32(catId), false);
            var path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("22-02-2014__000865.jpg");  
            File.Delete(path);
            return cart.TotalQuantity().ToString();    
    }
```